# Product discontinued with very similar alternative available

Tags: redirect, seo

We've got a product listed which has generated quite a buzz. I know that there's quite a lot of inbound links to it. We've now realized it's being discontinued but a very similar replacement model is available.

What is the best practise in Magento for implementing redirect in an SEO-optimized manner in which link juice will be preserved.

I've read t[his article on Moz](https://moz.com/blog/determining-whether-a-page-site-passes-link-juice) which states:

> Since 301s lose some link juice in the process and good anchor text is so valuable for ranking in Google

Which strategy can I employ with Magento to maintain as much of the link juice as possible while re-directing to the updated model of this product, which is replacing said discontinued unit?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a question with opinion based answers, but I would go with the simplest and easiest to implement approach.
Leave the product enabled, just make it out of stock. You may even remove it from all the categories and make it not searchable, but this is not mandatory.  This way the URL still works.
On the product page, just show a message saying "this product is discontinued" (or something like that). "We recommend you the updated model(s)". And present a list of products you want the user to see.

It's simple because you don't need to code much.
You just have to add a new product attribute called 'discontinued' to know when to show the message and you can use the 'up-sells' to show updated models.

And all your old urls still work. So no redirects.

Comment: Thanks @Marius. I've flagged the question for closure. Appreciate the input.

Comment: @moose. No need to close it for now. In my opinion is half opinion based, half technical, I'm sure there are a lot of people with similar issues as yours. I had to deal with this before and I took the approach I described with one minor modification. I didn't use 'up-sells' to show the updated models, I created a new type of product association. The client was happy with this approach.